# Как правильно проситроить объекст javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Пишу на React приложение. Есть состояние, в котором следующее поле `panelClassesActive`, это объект, который содержит данные об активных элементах.

Есть функция `changeClass`, которая принимает в параметры ключ, который нужно поменять.

Вопрос в следующем, как мне поменять состояние так, чтобы все элементы внутри объекта `panelClassesActive` остались прежними, но менялось лишь одно поле, которое передано аргументом.

Т.е. например я сделал так:

```
changeClass('benefitsPanel');
```

И теперь в моем состоянии в котором уже

```
panelClassesActive: {
    benefitsPanel: true //зачение поменялось на противоположное,
},
```

```js
this.state = {
  panelClassesActive: {
    benefitsPanel: false,
  },
}

this.changeClass = function(changeKey) {

  console.log(1);

  this.setState({
    panelClassesActive: {
      ...this.state.panelClassesActive,
    }
  })

  console.log(this.state.panelClassesActive)

}
```

Comment: `panelClassesActive: {
      ...this.state.panelClassesActive,
    [changeKey]: !this.state.panelClassesActive[changeKey]
    }`

Comment: Чего-чего Вы хотите правильно сделать? :) `проситроить`?